# Renaming Column names in hive ORC table is resulting in NULL values in the New column

Tags: hive, alter, orc

I´m trying to rename the column name in hive (ORC table) table using alter command. Columns are getting renamed however data is getting modified to `Null` values.

Example:

```
select city from p_details;

city

Santa Fe Springs
Jiangmen

**alter table p_details change city city_name string;**

select city_name from p_details;

city_name

NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment): "The column change command will only modify Hive's metadata, and will not modify data. Users should make sure the actual data layout of the table/partition conforms with the metadata definition.", which implies that the column change will not change any underlying data if it is an orc or parquet table.
Try to execute `msck repair table <table_name>`, but it may not help.

You can always create a new table with renamed column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it should not change the data. But I am seeing Null values. I tried msck repair also that did not help. I will recreate the table for now.